# Phonegap build geolocation Error calling method on NPObject

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a problem with the phonegap/cordova geolocation plugin.
I'm creating a application that uses the users geolocation to check if they are close to a position and then do some stuff with that.

I kept getting this error: Error calling method on NPObject.
I moved the code around and created some new functions to have more specific functions and found the failing code.

I put it in a try ... catch to get better errors:

```
getLocation: function()
{
    try
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log("Error code: "+err.code);
        console.log("Error message: "+err.message);

    }
}
```

But I still only get the same error
Error code: undefined
Error message: Error calling method on NPObject.

I'm using phonegap build and have added the plugin for geolocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you try, using method called from javascript interface, to interact with UI. Solve it in this way:

```
class mJSInterface()
{

public void myFunction()
{
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //Code that interact with UI
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: I'm not interacting with the UI with that function(or the onSuccess). And even if I run the function from the console in phonegap builds debug-mode I get the same error. It works like a charm in my browser.