# Error calling method on NPObject in FileReader in cordova app (Intel xdk android build)

Tags: android, cordova, filereader, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I was trying to follow [this instructions](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) to be able to read files.

As a result I do have access to the file system BUT reading file produce an error:

> Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject

Fun part is that if I try to call `readAsText(file)` function for the second time The file reader finally reads a file but still produce the same error.

How to avoid this error and how to make fileReader work in the first call?

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readAsText(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Read File</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try, using method called from javascript interface, to interact with UI.

Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832398/phonegap-build-geolocation-error-calling-method-on-npobject/19832468#19832468)

Comment: Where did I use method called from js interface? The error appears at **reader.readAsText(file)** command.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason following code works from the first time but still produces same error.

```
function gotFile(file){
    readAsText(file);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(){}, fail);
}
```

Could anyone explain this behavior?